# Error while saving custom connector in microsoft teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, office365connectors

I am using the app studio on Microsoft Teams to build a connector for an app. The manifest.json which is created by app studio is as follows :

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.6/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "manifestVersion": "1.6",
    "version": "1.1.9",
    "showLoadingIndicator": true,
    "id": "bba38a7c-10d8-4015-94f8-0c0970f85f5a",
    "packageName": "com.cronycle",
    "developer": {
        "name": "Cronycle",
        "websiteUrl": "https://microsoft-teams-test-app.s.cronycle.com",
        "privacyUrl": "https://microsoft-teams-test-app.s.cronycle.com/privacy.html",
        "termsOfUseUrl": "https://microsoft-teams-test-app.s.cronycle.com/tou.html"
    },
    "icons": {
        "color": "color.png",
        "outline": "outline.png"
    },
    "name": {
        "short": "Cronycle",
        "full": ""
    },
    "description": {
        "short": "Cronycle app to test connectors",
        "full": "I like cronycle, so I made this app to check how the integration will work"
    },
    "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "connectors": [
        {
            "connectorId": "fb154f02-b6f7-411e-ae03-19a1306145a8",
            "configurationUrl": "https://microsoft-teams-test-app.s.cronycle.com/cronycleTestAppConnector/config.html",
            "scopes": [
                "team"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "identity",
        "messageTeamMembers"
    ],
    "validDomains": [
        "microsoft-teams-test-app.s.cronycle.com"
    ]
}
```

The connector renders fine. However, when I click on the save button, it gives me the following error :

````
2020-05-24T21:35:44.640Z Received error from connectors {"seq":1590354365723,"timestamp":1590356144627,"flightSettings":{"Name":"ConnectorFrontEndSettings","AriaSDKToken":"d127f72a3abd41c9b9dd94faca947689-d58285e6-3a68-4cab-a458-37b9d9761d35-7033","SPAEnabled":true,"ClassificationFilterEnabled":true,"ClientRoutingEnabled":true,"EnableYammerGroupOption":true,"EnableFadeMessage":false,"EnableDomainBasedOwaConnectorList":false,"EnableDomainBasedTeamsConnectorList":false,"DevPortalSPAEnabled":true,"ShowHomeNavigationButtonOnConfigurationPage":false,"DisableConnectToO365InlineDeleteFeedbackPage":true},"status":500,"clientType":"SkypeSpaces","connectorType":"fb154f02-b6f7-411e-ae03-19a1306145a8","name":"handleMessageError"}```
````

Comment: Could you please confirm if you have set validity state to true in your configuration page as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-creating#integrating-the-configuration-experience)

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT thank you for the prompt response. Yes, i've set setValidityState to true when a color is selected and after that i've done, microsoftTeams.appInitialization.notifySuccess(); So, the save button becomes active after a color is selected. That part is working fine. The issue arises when the save button is clicked.

Comment: Are you calling microsoftTeams.settings.setsettings() in your connector configuration page? Could you please confirm if you have added contentUrl in valid domains of your connector in connector dashboard? Please confirm if all the URL's you are trying to load are https url's.